# Put HTML code inside document.write

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I want to put this HTML inside document.write. How would I do that because the quotes get messed up when I try to.

```
<a href="Home Page.html"
onMouseOver="document.thereg1.src=red1.src"
onMouseOut="document.thereg1.src=reg1.src">
<img src="1.gif" Name="thereg1"></a>
```

Comment: The escape character for javascript is \ so you need to escape your quotes like so `"<a href=\"Home Page.html\" .... </a>"`

Comment: ...and your questions is probably being downvoted because you shouldn't be using `document.write` to create html content. Instead look at creating a new node and setting the html content of that instead

Answer (score 1):

As the comment says you shouldn't really use `document.write` but if you have to you can do:

```
document.write(
'<a href="Home Page.html"' +
'onMouseOver="document.thereg1.src=red1.src"' +
'onMouseOut="document.thereg1.src=reg1.src">' +
'<img src="1.gif" Name="thereg1"></a>'
);
```